# how to concat fixnum and string in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

i want to contat my static id + looping primary key id

```
 <% @user.each do |employee| %>
   <td><%=employee.username%></td>
   <td>
     <%= link_to 'activate', activate_path(id: employee.id), method: :patch, id: "activate"+"<%=employee.id%>".to_s %>
   </td>
 <% end %>
```

The `id: "activate"+"<%=employee.id%>".to_s` part isn't working.

Comment: You cannot concat a fixnum and a string.

Comment: I think it's pretty clear what they meant...

Comment: @sawa `'are you sure'.concat(63)` ;-)

Comment: @Stefan Good point, but that fixnum is actually just describing a single-character string. The method name is ineeed `concat`, that it is not concatenation of a string with a fixnum. And also, it is concatenation of a string with a fixnum, not concatenation of a fixnum with a string.

Comment: Do you really know how erb tag works?

Answer (score 3):

This way

```
"activate" + employee.id.to_s
```

works because you concatenate two strings

or this one

```
"activate#{employee.id}"
```

interpolation calls `to_s` for the expression passed

Answer (score 0):

First if you are providing collection, it must be **plural**, so use `@users` instead of `@user`. (Follow conventions for readability)

```
 <% @users.each do |user| %>
   <td><%=user.username%></td>
   <td>
     <%= link_to 'activate', activate_path(id: user.id), method: :patch, id: "activate#{user.id}" %>
   </td>
 <% end %>
```